# Is $e^{\sqrt{2}}\gt 3$ or $e^{\sqrt{2}}\lt 3$

Tags: real-numbers, irrational-numbers

$e^{\sqrt{2}}\gt 3$ or $e^{\sqrt{2}}\lt 3$  which  one  holds  true $?$   I  know  that  $2\lt e \lt 3$ and $\sqrt{2}\gt 1$. Little  help  on  how  to  use  them  to  find  the  right  inequality.

Thanks  for  any  help.

Answer (score 10):

Using the series of $\exp$ we have $e^{\sqrt{2}} \ge 1 + \sqrt{2} + \frac{2}{2!} > 3$.

Comment: The first inequality can be strict.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use that $e>2.7$ and $\sqrt 2> 1.4$, then
$$e^{\sqrt 2} > 2.7^{1.4} = (1+1.7)^{1.4} > 1+1.4\cdot 1.7 = 3.38$$
by [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).